# Is there a way I can transfer a smart object's animation to the original file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, smartobject

I am using Photoshop 2020.

I have a mockup of a laptop with a smart object as the screen. I created a scrolling animation within the smart object. Is there a way to transfer this animation so that it shows up in the original file? I want it to look like the website is scrolling on the picture of the laptop.

(I realize that doing this without a smart object is probably easier, however it can only be done with a straight-on view of a laptop since keyframes cannot be created with transformed objects. I would like the laptop to be at an angle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done unfortunately. Photoshop isn't really a good choice for animating anything except for maybe hand-drawn animation *to some extend*.

You can still salvage your animation:

- render the contents of your Smart Object to video (`File > Export > Render Video`);
- use `File > Import > Video Frames to Layers` in your original file: this will load all the frames as separate layers;
- you can then select them all and transform to fit the screen of the laptop photo;
- open Timeline and use `Create Frame Animation` command to be able to animate your laptop
- Add frames while toggling visibility of your animation layers one by one
- next time use After Effects